# Android 3D effect image gallery

Tags: android, image-gallery

I have an android app and i need to make an image gallery looks like this image [image: cover flow gallery]

but i don't know how to implement this gallery and how to make this effect on it .i just need a steps to follow or any code to understand 
any help please 
Thank you

Comment: How have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Demo for you here. I hope that it can help you.
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html
http://www.studyoverflow.org/2013/07/cover-flow-type-gallery-layout-in.html